# What is the most character-effient way to generate 15 html-nodes?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on the fizzBuzz problem and I would like to make a solution with pure css/html.

I need to render a ordered list with 15 empty html elements with as little code as possible. Is there any shorter way to do this without javascript?

this is what I need:

```
<ol><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ol>
```

Comment: Without a programming language? Afaik no...

Comment: Yes, no othe language allowed :)

Comment: hmmm use your keyboard :D

Comment: Emmett `ol>li*15` but that's cheating

Comment: I would love some feedback on the close-vote!

Answer (score -2):

In 69 character:

```
<ol><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li></ol>
```

Now this is valid!

https://validator.w3.org/check

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li><li></ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is riddled with validation errors: **Self-closing syntax (`/>`) used on a non-void HTML element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag.** This treats every `<li/>` as `<li>` instead, which ultimately leads to a markup which looks something like: `<ol><li><li><li>...</li></li></li></ol>`... which is also invalid. Whilst some browsers may be able to fix this, the majority will not.